# bootstrap datepicker show month number insted of if month name

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

is there any way to show the month number instead of month name in the calender grid?

because Now I can see the calncer as Jan 2014 , Feb 2014 ... etc

is there any way to show the month number like 1 2014 , 2 2014

Thanks

Comment: $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
})

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine this 'months' array before calling datepicker init:

```
$.fn.datepicker.dates['en'] = {
    days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
    daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
    daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
    months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    today: "Today",
    clear: "Clear"
};
$('#your_datepicker_id').datetimepicker();
```